# Java | how can I use multiple methods to print out grade scores?

Tags: java, loops, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BA4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello Drews, how many total grades do you want to process?");

    int numberOfGrades = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] storeGrades = new int[numberOfGrades];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter grade " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        storeGrades[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Total score is: " + (getTotalScore(storeGrades)));
    System.out.println("Lowest score is: " + (getLowestScore(storeGrades)));
    System.out.println("Highest score is: " + (getHighestScore(storeGrades)));
    System.out.println("Average score is: " + (averageScore(String.format("%.2f", storeGrades))));
}

public static int getTotalScore(int[] storeGrades) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < storeGrades.length; i++) {
        sum += storeGrades[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int getLowestScore(int[] storeGrades) {
    int getLowestScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i > storeGrades.length; i++) {
        getLowestScore = storeGrades[i];
    }
    return getLowestScore;
}

public static int getHighestScore(int[] storeGrades) {
    int getHighestScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < storeGrades.length; i++) {
        getHighestScore = storeGrades[i];
    }
    return getHighestScore;
}

public static double averageScore(double[] storeGrades) {
    double averageScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < storeGrades.length; i++) {
        averageScore = (double) storeGrades[i];
    }
    return averageScore;
}

public static int printGrade(int[] storeGrades) {
    int printGrade;
    if (printGrade > 89) {
        String gradeSoFar = "A";
        System.out.println("Your grade so far is an " + gradeSoFar);
    }
    else if ((printGrade > 79) && (printGrade < 90)) {
        String gradeSoFar = "B";
        System.out.println("Your grade so far is a " + gradeSoFar);
    }
    else if ((printGrade > 69) && (printGrade < 80)) {
        String gradeSoFar = "C";
        System.out.println("Your grade so far is a " + gradeSoFar);
    }
    else if ((printGrade > 59) && (printGrade < 70)) {
        String gradeSoFar = "D";
        System.out.println("Your grade so far is a " + gradeSoFar);
    }
    else if ((printGrade > 0) && (printGrade < 60)) {
        String gradeSoFar = "F";
        System.out.println("Your grade so far is an " + gradeSoFar);
    }
    return printGrade;
}
}
```

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong. I have a couple of errors which leads me to believe I really just don't understand methods as well as I thought I did.
The goal is to create 5 methods displaying to the user the total, lowest, highest and average scores, and then to print the letter grade. Thank you for your assistance to this noobie java coder! :)

Comment: `System.out.println("Your grade so far is a " + gradeSoFar);` is redundant, can be out of `if` and put just before the `return`

Comment: "_I have a couple of errors_" And they are...?

Comment: @person Don't edit out lines of code in posts.

Comment: @azro so i can just leave the string out and just have it print out gradeSoFar?

Comment: Inline the 2 lines , OR create the variable before , associate it in the if, and print after

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a `String` when you should be passing in a `Double[]` into `averageScore` function in this line:

```
System.out.println("Average score is: " + (averageScore(String.format("%.2f", storeGrades))));
```

and you did not initialize the `printGrade` variable inside the `printGrade` function, you need to give it an initial value if you are going to use it in a comparison.

That's all the errors that